# Can't set Checked property of a TreeNode in the AfterCheck event

Tags: c#, treeview, checked

I have a simple TreeView (several parents and 1 level of children each) in C# 2008 (.Net 3.5) on Vista.

In the AFterCheck routine I am attempting to set/unset the Checked property of the child nodes based on the state of the parent when it is clicked with the mouse.

Using MessageBoxes, I can see the event routine entered and the loop through the child nodes and if the parent is checked, the code

```
childnode.Checked = parentNode.Checked;
```

shows via the MessageBox.Show(childnode.Checked + " " + parentNode.Checked); following the execution of the code shows  "False True" and the child checkbox remains unchecked in the TreeView.

I have tried several variations found on the web with the same result.  I even tried a replacement TreeView (MWControls) with exactly the same results.

Interestingly, any other childnode property (say BackColor) I set takes effect.

I believe that recursion is not an issue and seems to be verified by the debugging MessageBoxes.

Any ideas?

Regards,
Jim

---

This is a winform application.

I removed all of the MessageBox calls with no change; child nodes still not checked in response to the parent being checked.

I removed my AfterCheck routine and used the one referenced *verbatum* with the same results; child nodes not checked in response to the parent being checked.

I have played with this for hours with no luck.

The strange thing is that any other property I change (like BackColor) takes effect.

I did see an obscure reference on the web to this being a issue in Win7 but I can't find it again. Anyway, I am using Vista, .Net 3.5, and C# Express 2008.

Thanks for the input.

Regards,
Jim

Comment: Can you post your `AfterCheck` event handler?

Comment: *Never* debug event handlers with MessageBox.  It pumps a message loop, causing Windows events to get delivered out-of-order.  Use a debugger breakpoint or Debug.Print() instead.  Assigning the Checked property causes the AfterCheck event code to run again, avoid this with a bool variable.

Comment: Is this wpf, winforms or asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

[This example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aftercheck.aspx) does what you need. Most likely your code isn't working because setting the child's Checked property is propogating the event again, and you're not checking for the `Unknown` action as the linked-to code does.